# Override quill toolbar's after selector

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors, quill, react-quill

Quill toolbar is injecting a ":after" selector automatically and I want to override its ":after" selector because it's creating extra unneeded spacing for me

this is how it looks like when I inspect Quill toolbar
[image]

I've tried adding this but it didn't work for me

```
style={{
      '&.ql-snow.ql-toolbar:after, .ql-snow .ql-toolbar:after': {
        display: 'none !important',
      },
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make it go away but I can't really see any difference after it's removed

```
.ql-snow.ql-toolbar:after, .ql-snow .ql-toolbar:after {
    display: none;
}
```

You can access that toolbar with this and play around with margins or padding to make it smaller

```
.ql-snow.ql-toolbar, .ql-snow .ql-toolbar {
    padding: 0px;
}
```